# Shared memory and unix domain socket sync, without duplicate the shm content

Tags: c, linux, tcp, shared-memory, epoll

```
           connect()
Client 0 -------------
Client 1 ----------   \             accept()
       .           \   ------>  +-------------+
       .            --------->  |  TCP server |  <--- Dispatcher process.
       .            --------->  |-------------|
Client N ----------/            |  IPC server |
                                +-------------+
                                 /    /     \
                                /    /       \   <--- Pass file descriptor
          ---------------------/    /         \       to less stressed worker.
         /                         /           \
        /                         /             \
       |                         |              |
+-------------+    +-------------+       +-------------+ Workers are processes,
|  Worker #0  |    |  Worker #1  |  ...  |  Worker #M  | and use epoll to
+-------------+    +-------------+       +-------------+ send(), recv().
       |                  |                     |
       |     #0           |     #1              |     #N
Shared | memory    Shared | memory       Shared | memory
+-------------+    +-------------+       +-------------+
|   rw_lock   |    |   rw_lock   |       |   rw_lock   |
|-------------|    |-------------|       |-------------|
|   User #0   |    |   User #1   |       |   User #2   |
|-------------|    |-------------|       |-------------|
|   User #3   |    |   User #4   |  ...  |   User #5   |
|-------------|    |-------------|       |-------------|
|      .      |    |      .      |       |      .      |
|      .      |    |      .      |       |      .      |
|      .      |    |      .      |       |      .      |
+-------------+    +-------------+       +-------------+

The workers communicate with each other through the IPC socket server.

Imagine the following situation:

Worker #0 have 100 succesful login, so it may have to send a userlist of
one hundred, but meanwhile in Worker #1 (for example) User #1 send message:
"bye", and disconnect from the server. So, what is happening:

Worker #0 epoll list:     Worker #0 reaction:
  - recv()                 - send(nicklist)
  - recv()                 - send(nicklist)
  - ...                    - ...

Worker #0 lock SHM #0, SHM #1, ..., SHM #M, and assemble the user list, and
send out.

Meanwhile when try to lock SHM #1, dont succesful, because Worker #1 locked
it for write: remove the disconnected client. (And Worker #1 send two messages
to IPC server: message from user (bye), client (xy) is disconnected).

So, now Worker #0 epoll list:
Worker #0 epoll list:     Worker #0 reaction:
  - TCP recv()                 - send(nicklist)
  - TCP recv()                 - send(nicklist)
  - ...                        - ...
  - IPC recv()                 - send_broadcast_to_my_clients(xy msg: bye)
  - IPC recv()                 - send_broadcast_to_my_clients(xy disconnected)

And what the clients are look:
 - I have a nicklist, where User #1 does not exist, but he say: "bye", and quit.
   (Is he a ghost?)
```

The question is: **how can I sync that?**

I've been thinking a lot about what would be the solution.

I got this:

Don't use shared memory, all worker store a global userlist (what is syncronized by IPC socket), but this solution is too memory-intensive.

Answer (score 1):

It is very difficult to give you a sensible answer, as you've already decided on things that make little sense. Your question is a loaded foot-gun, and any answer will be deficient.

For example, this is all incorrect:

> Meanwhile when try to lock SHM #1, dont succesful, because Worker #1 locked
>   it for write: remove the disconnected client. (And Worker #1 send two messages
>   to IPC server: message from user (bye), client (xy) is disconnected).

You don't *"try"* to lock, you *lock*. The locking operation will block until it can be satisfied. Ergo, no issues similar to the ones you described.

This means that you do need to minimize the time you keep the structure locked, especially for write locks. For example, you never send or receive data while keeping the structure locked: you copy the necessary parts from the structure to a temporary (dynamically allocated) buffer, release the lock, and then send the (messages based on the) buffer contents.

If you already have the shared memory, why would you use an IPC server? The shared memory segment is already a fully-featured IPC mechanism, so why would you make everything more complex for no gain? The original process should only manage the child processes.

Finally, you've already decided to use processes, while this design is much more workable with threads (pthreads). For example, if you were using threads, each worker could send targeted messages to any client directly, if the shared memory contains also the file descriptors.

You have encountered problems, and are asking how to fix a solution path you have already chosen. That is wrong. You should ask what is wrong with your design as you are having difficulty in implementing it, and how to fix your design.

Comment: You don't understand the example. Beetween two "lock-release" come the third "lock-release" (writer), and change the data. And that's, why second (read) "lock-release" get not current data. (In lock queue: read, read..., write, read, read...) And send() MSG_OOB flag not a solution, because epoll_write return more event at time.

If shared memory is full-featured IPC, then how can i pass file descriptor with it? And how can alert epoll about: i changed the shared memory? If I have socket for fd passing, why not use it for notify epoll?

Comment: @bsz: The example will not work: it is a broken design. You cannot fix it by adding more stuff into it. You need to change the design to fix the problems. Your question is *"How I can sync [this broken design]?"*, and my answer is *"Do not (even try). The design is broken. Fix the design instead, and you get rid of these problems for free."* If you care to edit your question to describe what you are attempting to construct, in broad terms, I shall try and describe a logical structure that would avoid these issues.